# bezier line in konvajs is not the normal bezier

Tags: konvajs

I want change normal line to bezier curve with this:

```
var grayBezierLine = new Konva.Line({
  points: [50, 50, 100, 100, 150, 50, 200, 100, 250, 50, 300, 100, 350, 50],
  stroke: 'gray',
  strokeWidth: 15,
  lineCap: 'round',
  lineJoin: 'round',
  bezier: true,
});
```

but the display is weird, after check the sourcecode, found this:

```
if (bezier) {
    // no tension but bezier
    n = 2;

    while (n < length) {
      context.bezierCurveTo(
        points[n++],
        points[n++],
        points[n++],
        points[n++],
        points[n++],
        points[n++]
      );
    }
  }
```

At first I thought except the first(50, 50) point and last point(350, 50), all intermediate points are control points, but it's not, every three points forms a curve.

[this is](https://codepen.io/navono/pen/PBgQWe?editors=1010)  a reproduce demo.

My question is this a deliberate design or a bug?

Comment: It's a 4-point Bezier. Have a look at the explanation [here](https://javascript.info/bezier-curve) - scroll down a couple of times and there are some animated examples that really help. The first 4-point solution matches your path. The source code takes point 1 as the first two path values, then uses the following 3 pairs as the 'other' 3 points for the 4-point Bezier.